# Setting default values to a function/package R

Tags: r, function, package, default

I've made a package with a function that asks for 3 values, like so:

```
example.foo("directory",vA1,vA2)
```

Now, I want to set a default value for both vA1 and vA2. I wrote the following piece of code, but I don't know why it ain't working

```
  if (!exists("vA1")) {
    vA1 = 2
  }
```

2 being the default value for vA1. When I run the package I get an "argument "vA1" missing, with no default". How do I set the default for this function? Thanks!

Comment: You should (re)read this: [Named arguments and defaults](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-intro.html#Named-arguments-and-defaults).

Comment: Thanks, I just didn't know how to look it up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Pascal points out, defaults to functions are provided by providing named arguments. For instance:

```
 fun <- function(x="Hello World") print(x)

 fun()
 [1] "Hello World"

 fun("and good bye")
 [1] "and good bye"
```

Comment: Thanks, I just didn't know how to look it up.